# Is there a word/idiom for a saying that explains "including something simply because you want to, even though it is not necessary"?

Tags: expressions, idioms

For clarification I will provide an example:

Assume that I've prepared for some test that is about X and Y.

When the test is handed to me, the questions are solely about X. I then want to jam/cram in my knowledge about Y, even though it is entirely irrelevant to the X-related questions.

Is there a saying for this, or would I just have to say, "doing something simply because you do not want it to go to waste"?

Comment: to cram for an exam has  nothing to do with shoving it.

Comment: We say to wing it, to wing an exam.

Comment: Sorry to have noticed, and your examples don’t match up.

Most obviously "doing something simply because you do not want it to go to waste" could never mean anything remotely similar to “including something simply because you want to, even though it is not necessary”. What part of that is not clear to you, please?

Answer (score 1):

**shoehorn**

In your case, the following definition from https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shoehorn applies:

> to force to be included or admitted

The example from that definition actually fits your example pretty well:

> shoehorned irrelevant arguments into his essay

As it applies to your question, you would be "shoehorning" your knowledge into your answers.